# Alignment Issue with vertical align

Tags: css, html

I'm using the below quoted HTML and CSS to create a bubble type `div`. Its `height` and `width` should adjust according to the content.

Every thing works perfect except the fact that I want to see all the `div`s in vertical order, what am I missing here?

Answers with a JSFiddle will be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="chat">
<div class="bubble me">Hello there!</div>

<div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
</div>
<div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
</div>
<div class="bubble me">Awesome. Awesome. Awesome. Awesome. Awesome.</div>
</div>
<div class="bubble me">Awesome.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat {
    width: 400px;
}

.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}

.me {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;         
}

.me::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;           
}
```

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mek5Z/1777/)

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mek5Z/1778/) added a clear:both; to the bubble.

Comment: You might want to remove some </div>s

Answer (score 4):

You can add `clear:left` to this class:

```
.me {
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;   
    clear: left;/*Add clear left*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mek5Z/1781/)

Take also a look here [Controlling flow next to floats: the 'clear' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control)

Answer (score 1):

add `clear: both` to bubble...
updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mek5Z/1782/